# jenkins how to enable checkout lightweight for pipelineJob?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

Here is my job DSL which creates pipelinejob in which script is taken from scm itself.

```
pipelineJob ("${jobName}_deploy") {
  description("built by seed")

definition {
     cpsScm {
        scm {
            git {
                remote {
                    url('gitUrl')
                    credentials('user_creds')
                }
              branch('master')
            }
        }
        scriptPath "scripts/pipeline/jenkinsfile_deploy"
    }
 }
 }
```

I need the lightweight checkout should be checked automatically.
[image]

any help would be more appreciated. I have so many jobs in which i need to open each and every job and click that check box which is painful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [Configure Block](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block) to add any option that is missing in the built-in DSL:

```
pipelineJob('example') {
  definition {
    cpsScm {
      // ...
    } 
  }
  configure {
     it / definition / lightweight(true)
  }
}
```

Comment: @daspiker Thank you so much. This is powerful. I am loving JOB DSL.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use [Configure Block](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block) for lightweight() but it **does not** work for me.

The thing I did to solve this issue is to use **cpsScmFlowDefinition()** like this:

```
pipelineJob('example') {
  definition {
    cpsScmFlowDefinition {
      scm {
        gitSCM {
          userRemoteConfigs {
            userRemoteConfig {
              credentialsId('')
              name('')
              refspec('')
              url('')
            }
          }
          branches {
            branchSpec {
              name('')
            }
          }
          extensions {
            cleanBeforeCheckout()
            localBranch {
              localBranch('')
            }
          }
          doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations(false)
          browser {
            gitWeb {
              repoUrl('')
            }
          }
          gitTool('')
        }
      }
      scriptPath('')
      lightweight(true)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.jobs.WorkflowJob.definition-cpsScm) wiki, this has to be like this

```
pipelineJob('job-name') {

  description('''
Job description
''')

  definition {
    cpsScm {
      lightweight(true)
      scm {
        git {
          remote {
            url('git@github.com:arulrajnet/attila.git')
            credentials('CREDENTIAL_ID')
          }
          branches('*/master')
        }
      }
      scriptPath('build.groovy')
    }
  }
}
```